# Which one is correct: please find the attached file or please find attached the file?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, email, correspondence

When we send professional email with attachments. Which one is correct?

1. please find the attached file or
2. please find attached the file

Or, is there any other sentence structure more suitable than above options.

Comment: *Please find the file attached.*

Comment: This expression is something of a “creative anachronism”, like closing an e-mail in a flowery style from the days of pen-and-ink correspondence. In some ways, the more strange-sounding version actually carries the greater charm. For practical correspondence, however, just use: *Please see the attached file.*

Comment: You will find the file attached (to this letter) → Please find, attached (to this letter), the file → (comma drop); also often “Attached please find”.

Comment: Please find a (the) file attached. Simple as that!

Comment: Please stop even thinking about the English wording and try this in your own language, then find a literal translation.

If that doesn't work for you, why not?

With great respect, "please find the attached (anything)…" is at best, silly.

By itself, "Please find attached the file" is meaningless but it might show you the correct form. Where is the rest of the sentence, which should have given that part meaning?

"Please find attached the file (FileName)" would work but why did you not realise the difference?

Answer (score 3):

The correct one of the two is

> Please find the attached file

Other options you might consider using:

- Please find the file attached
- Please find the file attached for your reference

Comment: I would not use any of these, but I would say *Please **see** the attached file*.

Comment: At the end of the day, there is nothing wrong with "The file is attached". Pleasantries can be used elsewhere. "Please don't hesitate to contact us if you need further information."

Answer (score 0):

I would never use "please find attached".  I always write, I have attached the documents you have requested.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to ELU. Please take the [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and consider how you might [improve your answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). As it stands, this sounds like opinion rather than evidence of general use.